# Why is the normal bundle of $\mathbb{R}P^1\subset\mathbb{R}P^2$ the Moebius Strip?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was studying basic differential topology and  [I came across to the assertion](https://montgomery.math.ucsc.edu/classes/mfds/normalbundle.pdf) that if we consider $S^1\subset S^2$ then we have a natural embedding $\mathbb{R}P^1\subset\mathbb{R}P^2$, and as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ we have that the normal bundle of $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is the Moebius Strip. But I couldn't find out a way to prove such assertion, can anyone help me?

Remark: The normal bundle of of a submanifold $N\subset M$ is the set $\cup_{p\in N}N_p$ where $N_{p}=TpM/TpN$.

Comment: Just draw a tubular neighborhood of the equator in $S^2$ and make the antipodal identifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch. Consider the canonical projection $p\colon S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{RP}^2$. It maps $S^1\rightarrow\mathbb{RP}^1$ via the canonical projection, is a local diffeomorphism and also an isometry with respect to the standard Riemannian metrics. For each $x\in S^1$, the isometry $dp_x\colon T_xS^2\rightarrow T_x\mathbb{RP}^2$ thus restricts to an isometry $N_xS^1\rightarrow N_x\mathbb{RP}^1$. In total, that implies the bundle map $dp\colon TS^2\rightarrow T\mathbb{RP}^2$ restricts to a surjective bundle map $NS^1\rightarrow N\mathbb{RP}^1$ (each laying over the respective canonical projection). I leave it as exercise to check that $NS^1\cong S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ is the trivial line bundle and to explicitly identify the constructed maps to see that it exhibits $N\mathbb{RP}^1$ as the quotient of $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ under the identification $(x,v)\sim(-x,-v)$ for each $x\in S^1,v\in\mathbb{R}$. It is another fun exercise to see geometrically that this quotient is none but the Möbius strip.

Answer (score 3):

An easy and intuitive way to see this is to construct the projective plane by glueing the sides of a square, much like the analogous construction of the torus and the Klein bottle by glueing:

[image: surfaces by glueing]

If you take as your circle the straight line that connects the centers of two opposite sides, it is immediately clear that you obtain the normal bundle by taking a symmetric strip around it, and gluing, giving you the Möbius strip.